# Por que este código dá segmentation fault?

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, falha-de-segmentação

Sempre que a primeira linha do mapa é preenchida ocorre um *segmentation fault*, gostaria de saber porque.

```
void newmap(int x, int y , int players){

    int linha,coluna;
    char **map = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * y);
    *map = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*x);

    for(linha=0; linha<x; linha++){
        for(coluna=0; coluna<y; coluna ++){

           if(linha == 0 || coluna == 0 || linha == (x-1) || coluna == (y-1)) {
               map[linha][coluna] = '*';
               printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Escolha uma resposta que respondeu à sua duvida, isso ajuda bastante a comunidade

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Você não está alocando cada linha, está alocando o geral e depois uma única linha, para alocar cada linha teria que cada uma delas dentro do laço de linhas. Não sei se dá o resultado esperado porque a pergunta não informa isto, e o código não dá maiores indicações, quem sabe até posso ser otimizado, mas seria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void newmap(int x, int y , int players) {
    char **map = malloc(sizeof(char *) * y);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        map[i] = malloc(x);
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == x - 1 || j == y - 1) {
               map[i][j] = '*';
               printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    newmap(3, 3 , 3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BPMgF8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cathmqii-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/SegmentationFault.c).

Answer (score 2):

Penso que queira fazer desta forma:

```
    /* Alocação dinamica relativamente à parte da linha*/
    char **map = (char **) malloc((sizeof(char*) * x)+1);

    /* Alocação dinamica relativamente à parte da coluna*/ 
    for(linha=0; linha<x; linha++)
        map[linha] = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)*y)+1);

    for(linha=0; linha<x; linha++)
    {
        for(coluna=0; coluna<y; coluna ++)
        {

            if(linha == 0 || coluna == 0 || linha == (x-1) || coluna == (y-1))
            {
                map[linha][coluna] = '*';
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Primeiro tem de alocar memoria para cada linha, depois **por cada linha** é preciso alocar memoria para a coluna.

Para ficar um codigo mais bonito podia colocar o 
`map[linha] =(char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*y)+1);` dentro do primeiro for, ficando um codigo mais limpo

Não esquecer de fazer depois o `free` corretamente, fazendo um ciclo para limpar cada coluna e so depois dar free ao map.